# arrayFilter MongoDB context is not defined

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Saludos estoy trabajando con mongoDB y nodeJs y tengo un inconveniente con el siguiente query:

```
  await this.update(
      { _id },
      { $set: { 'tour.$[elem].show': false } },
      { arrayFilters: [{ 'elem.number': { $in: steps } }] });
```

El campo al que estoy accediendo en mongoDB tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
"tour" : [
        {
            "show" : true,
            "number" : 1,
            "selector" : ".tour-search-input",
            "position" : "top",
            "title" : "tour_title_step_1",
            "content" : "tour_content_1"
        },
        {
            "show" : true,
            "number" : 2,
            "selector" : ".tour-dart",
            "position" : "top",
            "title" : "tour_title_step_2",
            "content" : "tour_content_2"
        },
        {
            "show" : false,
            "number" : 3,
            "selector" : ".tour-upload",
            "position" : "top",
            "title" : "tour_title_step_3",
            "content" : "tour_content_3"
    ]
```

Me genera el siguiente error en mongoDB, aguién sabrá de que se trata?

```
message: 'context is not defined',
```

¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Habría que ver a qué apunta `this`. Por lo visto estás usando algún método bien sea estático o de instancia. El error indica que el contexto (hacia donde apunta `this`) no está definido. ¿Puedes indicar el contexto desde donde llamas al método `update`? Saludos

Comment: Hola @MauricioContreras , ya sé cual es el error. Está en esta linea     { arrayFilters: [{ 'elem.number': { $in: steps } }] }), 

El arrayFilters no admite un objecto con una expresión dentro! El filtro debe ser un número por ejemplo:     { arrayFilters: [{ 'elem.number': 1] });

Hasta luego, gracias por responder.!

Comment: ¿De dónde sacas que **arrayFilters no admite un objecto con una expresión dentro**? Claro que recibe un objeto, el problema no está allí (al menos usando MongoDB v4.2.8. El problema es otro y tiene que ver con el enlace (*binding*) de tu variable `this`. Si puedes mostrar la forma en que estás usando el contexto de `this`, podría ver cuál es el problema. Tu código funciona perfectamente usando el objeto que pasas a `arrayFilters`, pero aplicando el método `update()` directamente al modelo (no a `this`). Por último, el método `collection.update()` está marcado como obsoleto. Saludos

Comment: Por lo menos en la versión que estoy usando en producción no lo admite, tengo un objeto con un array dentro del arrayFilters, la referencia con el this no tiene nada que ver El this dentro de un modelo se usa para instanciarlo a el mismo

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario @MauricioContreras, el método `update()` está aplicado directamente al modelo amigo, en nodejs se usa el `this` para instanciar al modelo que estás usando para la transacción, gracias !